# How to declare the variables which are of date type and to sort based on the date?

Tags: java, date, constructor

I have the transaction class where I have variables like Arrival date, departure date, I am not sure how to define the date data types, so that transaction info must be sorted on basis of start date. I want to give the date in an explicit manner to the class. For example, I want to give 5 dates and sort them. Can you please let me know, how to do that.

```java
public class Transaction implements Comparable<Transaction> 
{
    private Dog dogID;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date departureDate;
    private List<Integer> serviceLevel = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    private List<Integer> ratePerDay = Arrays.asList(89,129,149);
    private double totalcharge;
    private double deposit; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use only *java.time* classes, never legacy `Date` class.

Implement the one method required by `Comparable` interface.

```
@Override
public int compareTo( Transaction other )
{
    return this.startDate().compareTo( other.startDate()
}
```

## Details

Both `Date` classes included with Java are *terrible*, badly designed by people who did not understand date-time handling.

If you want a date only, without time of day, and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate departureDate;
```

If the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably, define the class as a record. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

And never use a floating-point type like `double` where accuracy matters such as moment. Use `BigDecimal` where accuracy trumps speed.

A list should generally be named in the plural, for clarity.

The Java naming convention is camelCase. So `totalCharge`.

```java
public record Transaction
(
    Dog dogID , 
    LocalDate startDate , 
    LocalDate departureDate , 
    List<Integer> serviceLevels , 
    List<BigDecimal> ratesPerDay , 
    BigDecimal totalCharge , 
    BigDecimal deposit
) {}
```

If you want to usually sort by the start date member field, implement the `Comparable` interface with its one required method, `compareTo`. We implement that method by calling upon the `compareTo` method built into the `LocalDate` class.

```java
public record Transaction implements Comparable < Transaction > 
(
    Dog dogID , 
    LocalDate startDate , 
    LocalDate departureDate , 
    List<Integer> serviceLevels , 
    List<BigDecimal> ratesPerDay , 
    BigDecimal totalCharge , 
    BigDecimal deposit
) 
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo( Transaction other )
    {
        return this.startDate().compareTo( other.startDate()
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to give the date in an explicit manner to the class. For example, I want to give 5 dates and output should be in sorted manner. Can you please let me know, how to do that.

Comment: @surya_sree Instantiate your `Transaction` objects number passing date values to constructor. Collect into an `NavigableSet` such as `TreeSet`. As you add objects to set, they are put into sorted order. Or put into a `List` and call `List#sort`. Both approaches have been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow.